# How can I know which ports are open on my android device and how to close them?

Tags: android, ports

Is there an easy way, to see which ports are open on my Android device and a way to close the open ports?

Answer (score 10):

1. Create a wifi hotspot on your phone
2. Connect your computer to the hotspot
3. use ipconfig or ifconfig to know the gateway IP adresse ( ie: your phone's IP adress )
4. Download nmap : http://nmap.org/
5. Use the nmap command :  nmap -sS -Pn -p-  your_phone_ip_adress

the open TCP ports will be shown as follow :

---

65531 closed ports PORT
STATE SERVICE 
53/tcp    open  domain
8187/tcp  open  unknown 
38647/tcp open  unknown
42761/tcp open 
unknown MAC Address: A4:9A:58:**:**:** (Samsung Electronics Co.)

---

- PS : For UDP ports use: nmap -sU -Pn -p-  your_phone_ip_adress

Comment: I guess the list here is the result for the open ports in TCP. Can you post the result for UDP so everyone have it here handy instead of setting up the ambience and texting by ourselfs?

Comment: If steps 1-3 are just to determine the IP address of the device, then you could also enable USB debugging on it and run `adb shell ip addr` and look at the address of the `wlan0` interface if it is on Wifi.

Comment: if I start nmap it kills the WiFi connection immediately ...

Answer (score 5):

You can determine the currently open ports by reading the textual /proc pseudo-files such as

```
/proc/net/tcp
/proc/net/udp
```

This is basically what a netstat command (where implemented) does - you may wish to find and examine the source of a simple netstat implementation (it should be possible to port such to java)

However, when running as an unprivileged app userid, you will only be able to close sockets belonging to your own process (or by roundabout means involving ptrace or process killing, other processes belonging to your userid).  Also note that closing a socket does not necessarily make that port available for immediate re-use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try different network commands through runtime and check the results

```
// netstat -lptu 
// netstat -vat 


Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("netstat -vat ");
```